# Flame composition types

Tags: thermodynamics

Can anyone define the atomic structure of a carbon fuelled flame. I have studied variations of flame patterns but this type seems to stand out.

Answer (score 0):

If it is pure carbon, it is quite difficult to form a flame. The possible molecular in the flame in air are,

$$C+O_2=CO_2$$
$$CO_2 \leftrightharpoons CO + O_2$$

Comment: That's interesting. I would like to compare it with HHO flame

Comment: I would like to read your findings.